# Java call through Jython (Python) to run Ansible scripts through the Anisble Python API

Tags: java, python, ansible, jython

I'm able to use [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) to call Python scripts through Java.

I'm also able to use Python to call [these Ansible scripts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html).

However i can't seem to get the right configuration in order for Java->Jython(Python)->Ansible

When i try to run the Python/Ansible API example above from Java(Jython) i currently get the following error:

```
------------------------------------
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

File "/home/asdev/pythonFiles/PythonAPIBridge.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader

File "/home/asdev/ansible/ansible/lib/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ansible import constants as C

File "/home/asdev/ansible/ansible/lib/ansible/constants.py", line 12, in <module>

from jinja2 import Template

ImportError: No module named jinja2

------------------------------------
```

I'm pretty sure this is due to not having run `source ./hacking/env-setup` which sets up $PATH, $PYTHONPATH, $MANPATH, $PYTHON_BIN, $HACKING_DIR and $ANSIBLE_HOME then calls setup.py

But if i try to run setup.py from withing Java (Jython execfile or runnable script) i get other issues:

```
------------------------------------
File "<string>", line 1, in <module> 

File "/home/asdev/ansible/ansible/setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    from distutils.command.build_scripts import build_scripts as BuildScripts

File "/home/asdev/jython2.7.0/Lib/distutils/command/build_scripts.py", line 11, in <module>
    from distutils import sysconfig

File "/home/asdev/jython2.7.0/Lib/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 28, in <module>
    project_base = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.executable))

File "/home/asdev/jython2.7.0/Lib/posixpath.py", line 367, in realpath
    path, ok = _joinrealpath('', filename, {})

File "/home/asdev/jython2.7.0/Lib/posixpath.py", line 373, in _joinrealpath
    if isabs(rest):

File "/home/asdev/jython2.7.0/Lib/posixpath.py", line 61, in isabs
    return s.startswith('/')

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
------------------------------------
```

Ansible Python API [code example here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html)

Ansible Source:

```
git clone https://github.com/ansible/ansible.git --recursive
```

Simple java code (if you need the interface or factory let me know but it is boiler plate):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    //props.setProperty("python.path", "/home/asdev/pythonFiles");
    props.setProperty("python.path", "/home/asdev/ansible/ansible:/home/asdev/ansible/ansible/lib:/home/asdev/pythonFiles");

    Properties preprops = System.getProperties();

    PythonInterpreter.initialize(preprops, props, new String[0]);

    PythonInterpreter inter = new PythonInterpreter();
    for(PyObject p : inter.getSystemState().path.asIterable()) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }

    //Try running setup.py from a file
    //inter.exec("execfile(\"/home/asdev/pythonFiles/runFile.run\")");
    //Try running setup.py
    //inter.exec("import sys");
    //inter.exec("sys.argv = ['egg_info']");
    //inter.exec("execfile(\"/home/asdev/ansible/ansible/setup.py\")");

    //Run Python scipt that calls Ansible
    PythonAPIFactory factory = new PythonAPIFactory("PythonAPIBridge");
    print(factory.create("test", "testing"));

    inter.close();
}
```

Commented out code is when i try to run setup.py before my PythonAPIBridge that tries to run Ansible.

I know about Ansible tower and i understand i could write a Java cli interpreter for Ansible but i'd prefer this solution.

Comment: Hi user2026410, welcome to SO. For that missing jinja2 problem, it's because you appear to have forgotten to [`pip install -r requirements.txt`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.7.11/requirements.txt) as described [in hacking's README](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/v2.7.11/hacking#env-setup)

Comment: In your traceback about `isabs`, you left off the **error message**, but I'd guess it is because `s` is `None`, so you'll want to define `sys.executable` in your jython interpreter (assuming my theory is right); in the future, please do include error messages in your questions

Comment: I did run "pip install -r requirments.txt" and it works from the cli as stated above. The problem is it doesn't work when run from java through jython.

Comment: I added the last line of the error not sure how it got cut off. Thanks for pointing it out.
I printed out sys.executable and from java/jython it is None. I will see if i can get farther after figuring out how to set it. Thanks.